# Query to find when a database role's permissions were changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, security, roles, database-roles

For a Microsoft SQL server, is there a query that shows the history of when and who changed a database role permission?

Is there combination of system views that show the following information?

For example:

```
Role    Permission             Modify_Date                 Grantor Name
public  Alter any certificate  2023-08-11 12:07:50.117     domain\user  (when they selected the permission)
public  Alter any certificate  2023-08-11 12:08:00.102     domain\user  (when they removed the permission)
```

[image]

Comment: Usually not historically unless you activated it ahead of time. You could check default trace or extended events if it shows something, or db log

Comment: Normally SQL Server does not track this sort of audit information, it's down to you to implement it; you could use SQL Server Audit or extended events